# Python logging time stamp convert to mysql timestamp

Tags: python, mysql, timestamp

I have a huge logging file with time stamp in the format like below:

```
08/07/2013 11:40:08 PM INFO
```

I want to convert that to mysql timestamp using python, like:

```
2013-04-11 13:18:02
```

I have written a python script to do that but I am wondering is there some build-in python package/function written already to do the timestamp routine work easily and more efficiently.

Since data 'massaging' is part of my daily work so any suggestion to the efficiency of my code or usage of new function or even new tools would be gratefully appreciate.

(Note: input file is delimited by ^A and I am also converting that to csv at the same time)

($ cat output.file | python csv.py > output.csv)

```
import sys

def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line[:-1]
        cols = line.split(chr(1))
        cols[0] = convertTime(cols[0])
        cols = [ '"' + col + '"' for col in cols ]
        print ",".join(cols)

def convertTime(loggingTime):
    #mysqlTime example: 2013-04-11 13:18:02
    #loggingTime example: 08/07/2013 11:40:08 PM INFO

    #DATE
    month, day, year = loggingTime[0:10].split('/')
    date = '/'.join([year,month,day])

    #TIME
    hour, minute, second = loggingTime[11:19].split(':')
    flag = loggingTime[20:22]
    if flag == 'PM':
        hour = str(int(hour) + 12)
    time = ":".join([hour, minute, second])

    mysqlTime = date + " " + time
    return mysqlTime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `time.strptime` to parse the time, then `time.strftime` to reformat to new format?

```
import time

input_format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p INFO" # or %d/%m...
output_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

def convert_time(logging_time):
    return time.strftime(output_format, time.strptime(logging_time, input_format))

print convert_time("08/07/2013 11:40:08 PM INFO")
# prints 2013-08-07 23:40:08
```

Notice however that `strptime` and `strftime` can be affected by the current locale, you might want to set the locale to `C` (it is internally used by the `datetime` module too), as the `%p` can give different formatting for AM/PM for different locales; thus to be safe you might need to run the following code in the beginning:

```
import locale 
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "C")
```

Comment: Just curious: str p time and str f time, what is the p and f here short for? p: parse? f: printf?

Comment: p: parse, f: format - just like in printf: print with format.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module. You can convert your date string into a python `datetime` object, which you can then use to output a reformatted version.

```
from datetime import datetime

mysqltime = "2013-04-11 13:18:02"
timeobj = datetime.strptime(mysqltime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
loggingtime = timeobj.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it, as suggested, with strptime like this:

```
converter="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p INFO"
result = dt.datetime.strptime("08/07/2013 11:40:08 PM INFO",converter)
```

<strike>Split is needed due to the "INFO"-String (edit: not needed)</strike>. Then parse with strftime:

```
result.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```